# How can I remove user from Hub?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm sending by ajax post request to a method in the controller a string 'userName' that I should kick.
Is it possible to remove the user from current hub calling the method in the controller?

```
  public ActionResult Kick(string userName)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        var user = userService.GetUserByName(userName);
        var room = chatRoomService.GetRoomById(user.ChatRoomId.Value);
        user.IsKicked = true;
        userService.LeaveRoom(user);
        hubContext.Groups.Remove(user.ConnectionIdInHub, room.Name);
        return Json(new {success = true});
    }
```

Could i somewhere in this method disconnect user from hub?

Comment: What should happen to the user when he was kicked? Depending on your architecture, a user is always connected to the hub.

Comment: he won't be receiving messages from active users anymore if in some way i'll close connection in hub for him

Comment: @Toni
He is connected to the hub while he is inside of chatRoom.
And when he leaves room signalR method disconnect him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Server Side-

You should store user's `connection ID` at the time of his connection.

Like this in server side-

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    Boolean isFoundAnydevice = false;

    if(receivedClientId.Length>0)   //With Param
    {
        int noOfSelectedDevice = _context.TargatedDevice.Where(x => x.PhoneId == receivedClientId).Count();
        if (noOfSelectedDevice > 0)
            isFoundAnydevice = true;
    }
    else   //With no Param
    {
        String deviceId = _context.Device.Where(d => d.ConnectionId == this.Context.ConnectionId).Select(d => d.ClientId).SingleOrDefault();
    int noOfSelectedDevice = _context.TargatedDevice.Where(x => x.PhoneId == deviceId).Count();
        if (noOfSelectedDevice > 0)
            isFoundAnydevice = true;
    }

    if (isFoundAnydevice)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(
                        receivedClientId + " added to Test group"
                        );
        Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, testGroupName);
    }   

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Then you can easily find the user's connection ID from DB.

Now you can easily stop the hub connection like this-

```
public Task Disconnect(string connectionId)
{
    try
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var connections = _registeredClients.Where(c => c.Value.Any(connection => connection == connectionId)).FirstOrDefault();

            // if we are tracking a client with this connection 
            // remove it
            if (!CollectionUtil.IsNullOrEmpty(connections.Value))
            {
                connections.Value.Remove(connectionId);

                // if there are no connections for the client, remove the client from the tracking dictionary
                if (CollectionUtil.IsNullOrEmpty(connections.Value))
                {
                    _registeredClients.Remove(connections.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(this, "Error on disconnect in hub", ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

More can be found in here.

### Client Side-

If you like to do it from client side, you can do this-

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

Hope you have your answer